# Can a join table be combined with another table?

Tags: database, schema, psql, join

The first image below is my database schema for a project that will use psql, ruby and active record.

While writing my schema, things got a bit complex. My "special_days" table ended up becoming a join table for "days_of_week" and "organizations". I'm assuming that this is not best practice and will end up causing me trouble.

In the second schema below, I made a separate join table for "days of week" and "organizations". My special_days table still needs to be associated with a day_of_week and an organization, so I think I have to keep the joining information in the special_days table. Is there a better way to do this? It seems that my second attempt is too repetitive.

These are my relationships:

days of week & organizations | many to many

city & organizations | one to many

organization & special days | one to many

day of week & special days | one to many

[image: Schema with "Special_days" acting as a join table]
[image: Schema with separate join table]

Comment: I think your second schema is indeed Representative and first one serves the purpose better... Let's see what others suggest..

Comment: Table names should be singular by convention (day_of_week, organization, city, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Some more information about the requirements might be useful.  Are you required to do something like define which days are holidays, which days are paydays, etc. (e.g. many organizations would define Sat and Sun as non-work days and many U.S. organization would define July 4 as a non-work day)?  I'm not sure what days_of_the week represents.  Is this a table with 7 records in it (M,T,W,Th,F,S,Sun)? If I'm guessing correctly at the requirements it might be better to do something like have a table called special_day that has a date column and a recurrence column (e.g. weekly, monthly, yearly, etc.).  You could then have a organization_special_day table that is a many-to-many join table on organization and special_day.